# Why do I see a device log entry for a cellular tethering configuration in Chrome OS?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome-os, tethering, configuration-managment

Today I noticed the following log entry in a Chromebook Chrome's Device Log:

```
Network Debug [2023/06/10 13:32:29.825898] shill_property_handler.cc:393 ManagerPropertyChanged: TetheringConfig = { "auto_disable": true, "band": "all-bands", "passphrase": "I_CHANGED_THE_ALPHANUMERIC_STRING", "randomize_mac_address": true, "security": "wpa2", "ssid": "I_CHANGED_THE_ALPHANUMERIC_STRING", "upstream_technology": "cellular" }
```

This can be accessed at chrome://device-log. Also, please note I have replaced the original passphrase and SSID with `I_CHANGED_THE_ALPHANUMERIC_STRING`.

I have not set this tethering configuration, and I am wondering:

- Is this tethering configuration a **preset** of Chrome OS (by preset I mean that the software developers have coded this, and **all** Chrome OS machines display this log entry)?
- If the answer to the previous question is yes, what is the purpose of having this preset configuration?

Regarding this particular machine (to prevent mistaken assumptions), I have **never** connected this Chromebook to any wireless technology, be it Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, or cell tethering. Since new, I toggled these off, and I have restricted this machine to connect to the internet **only** through a USB-C to Ethernet adapter wired to a cable modem that lacks wireless technology.